# MySQL + Python: bottle_mysql INSERT exception

Tags: python, mysql, bottle

I am using the **bottle_mysql** plugin in my web app. When I try to insert a row into the DB, I get an exception :

> mysql error

`col1` is unique type field, and I need to know when the user tries to insert a duplicate value:

```
app = bottle.default_app()
plugin = bottle_mysql.Plugin(dbuser='', dbpass='', dbname='')
app.install(plugin)

sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('{}', '{}')"
sql.format(request.POST.get('data1'), request.POST.get('data2'))

try:
    db.execute(sql)
except error as e:
    print e
```

Comment: Cleaned up grammar